# Access to previous scope in EJS

Tags: html, ejs

im creating my website using ***ejs***, and im trying to create a ***for loop inside a for loop***, but when i try to access to a value in the ***scope of the first loop*** i cant, theres any way to do that?

like this:

```
<% for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { %>
    <p><%= i %></p>

    <% for (let j = 0; j < array[i].object.length; j++) { %>
        <p><%= array[i].object %></p>
    <% } %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Not too familiar with EJS but have you tried `var` instead of `let` on the variable? I'm assuming its `i` that you're trying to access in the second loop and it isn't letting you.

Comment: yeah, i just tried but it still not working :(

Comment: I have just tested this on [EJS Playground](https://ionicabizau.github.io/ejs-playground/) and it seems to work fine for me, I can access `i` within the second loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you have posted your full code, but I see that you have not closed the first loop. But anyways ill assume that was not added by mistake.

EJS follows Javascript syntax. You should be able to access the variables or data from the parent loop in your child loop.

Just to put things clearly, here is what I would have done. Assume you have the following set of data.

```
students: [{
    name: ABC,
    age: 20,
    gender: male/female,
    scores: [
       {
         subject: 'physics',
         score: 70,
         maxScoreAllowed: 100
       }, .......
    ]
},.....]
```

For this, you can write your loop like this.

```
<% students.forEach(student => { %>
   <p><%= student.name =%>
   <% student.scores.forEach(score => { %>
       <p><%= score.subject + ' = ' + score.score + '/' + score.maxScoreAllowed 
       %>
       <!-- you can also access the student object here -->
   <% } %>
<% } %>
```

Hopefully, this helps you understand what exactly you are doing wrong.

Comment: Just to add on, you can create variables within the scope and use them inside your child's scope.